# How to return an exception to the calling program when an exception occurs in the called program, which has its own exception handling?

Tags: python, exception

I am looping over a list in a python program. For each item in the list, I call a function from a different python file which is imported in the current program. The file which has the called function has its own exception handling. I want the calling program to skip the current iteration of the loop when an exception occurs in the called program and continue with the next iteration of the loop. I tried using the `continue` keyword in the except clause of the calling program. But it's not working as I expected.

The structure of the program is like this -

**A.py**

```
import B

for item in list:
   try : 
       B.some_function(item)
   except Exception as err:
       continue
```

Note that the file **B.py** contains several functions having their own exception handling. The above code is terminating when the first exception occurs. I want it to get on with the next iteration of the loop.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You're code actually should work. Are you sure your list got more than 1 item? You should not catch `Exception`, but an explicit `Exception`, that you expect to happen (e.g. a `ValueError`). Actually, you don't need to use `continue`, you could just go with `pass`.

Comment: Do the functions in B return anything?

Comment: It is the expected behaviour since you do handle the exception within `B.some_function(item)` call, so you will never fall except block unless `B.some_function(item)` raise exception that is not handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need some extra signaling between `A` and `B`.  It will need to be a transparent addition to `B` that doesn't interfere with it's current behaviour.  Basically add something to `B`'s scope that can be modified by its exception handling and can be queried by `A`.

---

Depending on what else is in `B` - I was thinking a module level variable used as a flag that the try/except in `B` could change and the try/except in `A` could query.

**B.py**

```
#exception handling toggles this flag
exception_handled = False

def f():...
def g():...
...
```

**A.py**

```
import B

for item in list:
    try : 
        B.some_function(item)
        if B.exception_handled:
            #reset flag
            B.exception_handled = False
            raise Exception
            # or just
            #continue   
    except Exception as err:
        B.exception_handled = False
        continue
```

---

Or you could add an attribute/flag to the `B` functions that the exception handling could toggle and `A` could query.

**B.py**

```
#decorator to add flag to functions
def add_attr(func):
    func.exception_handled = False
    return func

@add_attr
def f():...
@add_attr
def g():...
...
#exception handler modifies a function attribute
#func.exception_handled = True
```

**A.py**

```
import B

for item in list:
    try : 
        B.some_function(item)
        if B.some_function.exception_handled:
            # reset flag
            B.some_function.exception_handled = False
            raise Exception
            # or just
            #continue   
    except Exception as err:
        B.some_function.exception_handled = False
        continue
```

---

I imagine it could become more elaborate like

A module level dictionary in `B` that holds the status for each of `B`'s functions.

**B.py**

```
exceptions = {}

def register(func):
    exceptions[func.__name__] = False
    return func

@register
def f():...
@register
def g():...

#exception handling -> exceptions[f] = True or exceptions[current_func] = True
```

Then `A` queries the dictionary:

```
        if any(B.exceptions.values()):
            #reset the flags
            for k in B.exceptions:
                B.exceptions[k] = False
            #raise exception
            #just continue
```

---

For those last two solutions you can determine the function name using the sys, traceback and/or inspect modules.  Once you have the name you can get a reference to the function itself through globals() or locals() as necessary.  Here is a quick example for stuff in `B.py`.

```
from pprint import pprint
import sys, inspect, traceback

exceptions = {}

def g():
    try:
        return 1 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        #find the function name as a string from the traceback
        typ, val, tb = sys.exc_info()
        # one way
        func_name0 = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1][-2]
        # another way via the frame object:
        # you have to get to the frame that caused the exception
        tb_x = tb
        while tb_x.tb_next is not None:
            tb_x = tb_x.tb_next
        func_name1 = tb_x.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
        print func_name0, func_name1
        # toggle the exeptions dictionary
        exceptions[func_name0] = True
        # get a reference to the function after finding the name
        func = globals()[func_name0]
        # and toggle its flag attribute
        func.exception_handled = True
        # what can you do with inspect
        # inspect.trace()[-1] contains the same frame object as tb_x
        pprint(inspect.trace()[-1])
        func_name2 = inspect.trace()[-1][-3]
```

As you can see from the print statements that is 2.7 code, I don't have 3.x on this machine.  There are some new methods in 3.x for the traceback and inspect modules that may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If `B.some_function(item)` never raises a single exception, then the `try` block is pointless.
You will never be able to catch any malfunction of `B.some_function` execution.
Therefore, you need `B.some_function` to actually raise an error.
So, "Why is this happening"? Simply because "[`some_function`] has its own exception handling".

If you have access to its code, you should edit it so as to let it actually raise an error when needed.

If you do not have access to its code, there are two possibilities:

1. The function was designed so that errors or malfunctions can be detected. Either errors are raised (and not caught) when needed, or the return value of the function tells if the operation worked or failed;
2. The function was designed so that it never gives any error, and that no malfunction can ever be detected.

If it's 1, alright, all you need to do is find and understand how to detect the error.
If it's 2, well, you can't (again, assuming you cannot edit the code).
If so, the way the function is meant to be used is probably different than the way you're trying to use it.

---

Since you do have the right to make minor changes to `some_function`, here is a fix that should not break any code relying on it, while allowing you to check if an error happened.

First, add a keyword argument to `B.some_function` that defaults to `None`.
This way, any code calling it will not break, since it will be set without being explicitly passed.
This parameter will behave as a flag: if it is raised, an error happened.
Here, "raised" means that its internal value is set to `True`.
If no flag is passed as parameter, then the behaviour stays the same.

```
"""B.py"""
def some_function(arguments..., myFlag=None):
    # stuff
    if error_happens():
        if myFlag is not None:
            myFlag.value = True
    # stuff
```

Now, in `A.py`, define a flag class.
A simple boolean value cannot be used, because it needs to be passed by reference to `B.some_function`, and to be modified by it.
`MyFlag` instances have a `value` attribute, that is set to `False` on initialization, and will be set to `True` when the flag needs to signal that something happened.

```
"""A.py"""
class MyFlag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = False

    # Just for more comfort: allows to write "if myFlag: ..."
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value

# Create a flag that will be down unless an error was raised
errorCaught = MyFlag()
# Call some_function and pass the flag as myFlag keyword argument
B.some_function(arguments.., myFlag=errorCaught)
# If errorCaught is True, then errorCaught.value is True as well,
# hence an error was detected
if errorCaught:
    print("An error got raised")
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought initially. The program B handles the exception on its own and thus the calling program A cannot detect the exception. I have access to the code of B but can't modify it as I please. I can however, make minor tweaks to it. Is there any other construct that I could use to get the behavior I want? I mean when an exception is found in B, can I let A know that an exception was encountered and return the control to it?

Comment: @RodrikTheReader Without breaking any code relying on `some_function`, that might be hard. I'm writing the code I have in mind, just wait a few minutes.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader Done. I'm adding explanation, but you can read the code now if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Below Example I define a custom exception **MyException** in Module  B.py and raise in function some_function. In Module A.py I use try and catch over calling b.py module`s some_function

**A.py**

```
from B import some_function , MyException

lst = [0,2,4,1,3]   # for example take it as list of number

for item in lst:
   try : 
       some_function(item)
   except MyException as err:
       print "error"
       continue
```

**B.py**

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def some_function(val):
    """ this function raise exception when val equal to 1 """
    if val == 1:     # for example raise exception when input is 1
        raise MyException
    else:
        print val
```

**Output**

```
0
2
4
error
3
```